# Android theme and style attributes difference "android:xxxx" vs "xxxx"

Tags: android, android-styles

I am now using AppCompat Theme to design UI. When styling this UI, i found some confuse about the style attributes.

Some of the item name, if not start with android:xxxx, compile will fail, not found the item name.

But some other, if start with android:xxxx, the style will not be applied.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/cursorColor</item>
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/textCursorColor</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarPopupStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="textCursorColor" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/text_cursor</item>
</style>
```

For example:

In the appTheme: if use **android:editTextStyle**, then the textCursorColor would not be applied.  So i need to remove "android:"

In the MyToolbarPopupStyle: if use **textColor**, will get compile error, no resource found that matched the attr. In this case, i need to add "android:".

Is there any rules for using? Or i need to try and error to add "android:" or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any rules for using? Or i need to try and error to add "android:" or not?

There are `attrs` and `styleable` attributes that part of the Android SDK that defines all of these values

In `styleable`,  `android:editTextStyle`    is [defined as the Default EditText style](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#EditText).

And in `attrs`, [it also says the same thing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html), but without `android:` prefix

Whether one works or not seems to be trial and error unless you are willing to dig into the source code for the custom attributes defined for those views/themes/styles. (In other words `android:` is defined in the base SDK)

As for the color, that is seen in [`TextAppearance` properties](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextAppearance)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The items names "android:" are the ones which are android specific whereas without android: are the custom attributes defined in theme or styles you are inheriting from.

For example "searchViewStyle" is the custom attribute defined in "ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"